# Backfitting implementation

Tags: r, machine-learning, python

I was wondering if anyone can help me with the implementation of the backfitting algorithm in R or python. I am trying to do an implementation on this algorithm but i can't find any resources on this, all the information i've found uses the gam function, i want to know if it's possible to do so without this functions.I really have no clue on how to start. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question is quite broad. Are there specific parts of the implementation you're having a hard time with? Is the code snippet on the second page of this pdf helpful at all, at least for clarifying your question? http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~cshalizi/350/hw/solutions/solutions-08.pdf. It might also help if you specify what steps you've taken thus far in trying to tackle this problem.

Comment: Yes this is actually quite helpful, it helps me understand the mathematical expression of the algorithm in code. That is the hard part for me, i understand the algorithm iterates over a function f until it converges, f is an smoothing function. I'm trying to do so over 2 predictors. Thanks for the paper, i think reading it would help me very much